Debugging AWS batch job
I have submitted a job to AWS Batch running on Fargate. The job description was added without problem, the job was submitted, but it never moves out of runnable status. The problem is there is no, or I don't know how to find an error message that would help me move forward with debugging.
Job deffinition:
{
  "jobDefinitionName": "diann-batch-job",
  "platformCapabilities": [ "FARGATE" ],
  "type": "container",
  "containerProperties": {
    "image": "111111.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/diann:latest",
    "resourceRequirements": [
      {"type": "MEMORY", "value": "16384"},
      {"type": "VCPU",   "value": "8"}
    ],
    "command": ["RANDOM_NUMBER=$RANDOM\necho \"Random number: $RANDOM_NUMBER\" > README.txt\n\n# Upload the README file to the specified S3 bucket\naws s3 cp README.txt s3://eliptica-batch-output/README.txt"],
    "jobRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::222222:role/AWS_Batch_Role",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::222222:role/AWS_Batch_Role",
    "environment": [],
    "ulimits": [],
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "/aws/batch/job",
        "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "diann"
      }
    }
  },
  "retryStrategy": {
    "attempts": 1
  },
  "timeout": {
    "attemptDurationSeconds": 432000
  },
  "tags": {
    "Name": "diann-batch-job"
  }
}


click on the batch job. It should show you detailed view / state of batch job. There will be something show there. If not, you can post the image with redacting important information
